# Debug Unit Test In Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, unit-testing, debugging, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I am using Visual Studio Code in Linux as my .NET CORE development environment. 
In this I would like to debug my unit-tests but i'm not able to do this. I have installed Omnisharp and with this i'm able to debug a normal dotnet program by adding a program.cs file. Then the breakpoint is hit.

Omnisharp is adding a debug test feature, but when i click on this, i get an error in the console (see below). When I run the tests without debugging it works fine.

```
dotnet-test Error: 0 : System.IO.InvalidDataException: Found invalid data while decoding.
   at System.IO.StringParser.ParseNextChar()
   at Interop.procfs.TryParseStatFile(String statFilePath, ParsedStat& result, ReusableTextReader reusableReader)
   at System.Diagnostics.ProcessManager.CreateProcessInfo(ParsedStat procFsStat, ReusableTextReader reusableReader)
   at System.Diagnostics.ProcessManager.CreateProcessInfo(Int32 pid, ReusableTextReader reusableReader)
   at System.Diagnostics.ProcessManager.GetProcessInfos(String machineName)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses(String machineName)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Test.TestCommand.RegisterForParentProcessExit(Int32 id)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Test.TestCommand.DoRun(String[] args)
```